# Suggestions for Document Previews in a Web App?

Tags: batch-file, openoffice.org

I'm building a medical billing and coding system and one of the specs is to show document previews. I don't need to be able to edit the documents in the preview area, but I do need to show them from within my app. I've experimented with Google Apps (don't like their TOS) and even entertained the notion of doing something like:

Use openoffice and make batch to save any doc to pdf for preview...editing follow these steps:

1. lock document
2. download
3. edit with any program word, excel, .... etc
4. upload
5. unlock document

The goal is that the excel files will be edited, but not within the app. It will be a simple check in/check out system, but in order to preview those documents I am having issues.

Any suggestions would be great. I'm not sure if I explained this well enough.